# Authorize.net SIM receive data and update database

Tags: php, mysql, authorize.net

I've signed up for Authorize.net and successfully:

1. Converted my shopping cart into data that sends TO Authorize.net and processes it.
2. Using Relay Response, sent user to my thank you page.

I cannot get my head wrapped around how to actually UPDATE my database once the transaction goes through.  What terms do I search for to figure this out?  Nearly all the documentation shows part of the solution but doesn't actually instruct on where to put it and how to receive it back.

On my Shopping Cart page, I have a list of hidden input fields that Authorize.net provides.  I plugged in my dollar amount, description, etc.  I assume I put another hidden field called "x_po_num" and have the value be my dynamic PO# in the database.

Isn't there a way to actually retrieve it on the Thank You page so I cross reference to the database and make simply add a value of "confirmed" or something?

How do I retrieve that value that was sent TO Authorize.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you get is simply in a `$_POST` array which you can `var_dump()` to see what values it contains.

Here's a sample relay response script in PHP:

```
<?php

// Retrieving and defining Form Data from Post command body from Authorize.Net
$ResponseCode       = trim($_POST["x_response_code"]);
$ResponseReasonText = trim($_POST["x_response_reason_text"]);
$ResponseReasonCode = trim($_POST["x_response_reason_code"]);
$AVS                = trim($_POST["x_avs_code"]);
$TransID            = trim($_POST["x_trans_id"]);
$AuthCode           = trim($_POST["x_auth_code"]);
$Amount             = trim($_POST["x_amount"]);

?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Transaction Receipt Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"></head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<?php
    // Test to see if this is a test transaction.
    if ($TransID === 0 && $ResponseCode === 1)
    {
        // If so, print it to the screen, so we know that the transaction will not be processed.
?>

    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <th><font size="5" color="red" face="arial">TEST MODE</font></th>
        <tr>
            <th valign="top"><font size="1" color="black" face="arial">This transaction will <u>NOT</u> be processed because your account is in Test Mode.</font></th>
      </tr>
    </table>

<?php
    }
?>

    <br>
    <br>

<?php
    // Test to see if the transaction resulted in Approvavl, Decline or Error
    if ($ResponseCode === 1)
    {
?>

    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <th><font size="3" color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">This transaction has been approved.</font></th>
      </tr>
    </table>

<?php
    }
    else if ($ResponseCode === 2)
    {
?>

    <table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th width="312"><font size="3" color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">This transaction has been declined.</font></th>
    </tr>
    </table>

<?php
    }
    else if ($ResponseCode === 3)
    {
?>

    <table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><font size="3" color="Red" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">There was an error processing this transaction.</font></th>
    </tr>
    </table>

<?php
    }
?>

    <br>
    <br>
    <table align="center" width="60%">
    <tr>
        <td align="right" width=175 valign=top><font size="2" color="black" face="arial"><b>Amount:</b></font></td>
        <td align="left"><font size="2" color="black" face="arial">$<?php echo $Amount; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right" width=175 valign=top><font size="2" color="black" face="arial"><b>Transaction ID:</b></font></td><td align="left"><font size="2" color="black" face="arial">

<?php
    if ($TransID === 0)
    {
        echo 'Not Applicable.';
    }
    else
    {
        echo $TransID;
    }
?>

    </td></tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right" width=175 valign=top><font size="2" color="black" face="arial"><b>Authorization Code:</b></font></td><td align="left"><font size="2" color="black" face="arial">

<?php
    if ($AuthCode === "000000")
    {
        echo 'Not Applicable.';
    }
    else
    {
        echo $AuthCode;
    }
?>

        </td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" width=175 valign=top><font size="2" color="black" face="arial"><b>Response Reason:</b></font></td><td align="left"><font size="2" color="black" face="arial">(<?php echo $ResponseReasonCode; ?>)&nbsp;<?php echo $ResponseReasonText; ?></font><font size="1" color="black" face="arial"></td></tr>
    <tr>

        <td align="right" width=175 valign=top><font size="2" color="black" face="arial"><b>Address Verification:</b></font></td><td align="left"><font size="2" color="black" face="arial">

<?php
    // Turn the AVS code into the corresponding text string.
    switch ($AVS)
    {
        case "A":
            echo "Address (Street) matches, ZIP does not.";
            break;
        case "B":
            echo "Address Information Not Provided for AVS Check.";
            break;
        case "C":
            echo "Street address and Postal Code not verified for international transaction due to incompatible formats. (Acquirer sent both street address and Postal Code.)";
            break;
        case "D":
            echo "International Transaction:  Street address and Postal Code match.";
            break;
        case "E":
            echo "AVS Error.";
            break;
        case "G":
            echo "Non U.S. Card Issuing Bank.";
            break;
        case "N":
            echo "No Match on Address (Street) or ZIP.";
            break;
        case "P":
            echo "AVS not applicable for this transaction.";
            break;
        case "R":
            echo "Retry. System unavailable or timed out.";
            break;
        case "S":
            echo "Service not supported by issuer.";
            break;
        case "U":
            echo "Address information is unavailable.";
            break;
        case "W":
            echo "9 digit ZIP matches, Address (Street) does not.";
            break;
        case "X":
            echo "Address (Street) and 9 digit ZIP match.";
            break;
        case "Y":
            echo "Address (Street) and 5 digit ZIP match.";
            break;
        case "Z":
            echo "5 digit ZIP matches, Address (Street) does not.";
            break;
        default:
            echo "The address verification system returned an unknown value.";
            break;
        }
?>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can also use [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/). Here is a [PHP tutorial](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/handling-authorize-net-silent-post-with-php/) that shows how to work with that.